# GitHub Actions Ignore Certain Files Inside a Directory

Tags: github-actions

I have a project where I use GitHub Actions. I now need to ignore certain file changes inside certain folders. Here is my project structure:

```
masterDir
 - contentDir
   - dir1
     - file1.ignore.md
     - file2.md
  -  dir2
     - file3.md
     - file4.ignore.md
```

So I would like that my GitHub actions are not triggered for any changes to any file that has ignore.md in its file name. So here is what I came up with, but that does not seem to work.

```
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'README.md'
      - 'backup/**'
      - 'masterDir/contentDir/**/*.draft.md'
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with my wildcard match?

Comment: Could you please edit the question/answer so the file names match the filter? The current 'ignore' vs 'draft' mismatch is confusing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was indeed quite simple to do. All I have to do is the following:

```
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'README.md'
      - 'backup/**'
      - '**/*.draft.md'
```

As a reference, here is the documentation in detail: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-file-paths

As it can be seen from the documentation that the wildcard matches any file in any folder that contains a .draft.md match.

Comment: Can you post the complete yaml file here?

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml

Comment: Thank much. What if I have to log the same list of files that were ignored? Like I have to log that so and so .md and .rst were changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in my workflows and it's working fine for me. please follow the below code.

```
on:
   push:
      paths-ignore:
         - '**/<dir-path>/**'
```